# initWithCVPixelBuffer failed because the CVPixelBufferRef is not non-IOSurface backed

Tags: ios, core-image

I receive YUV frames (kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange) and when creating a CIImage from a CVPixelBufferRef I get:

> initWithCVPixelBuffer failed because the CVPixelBufferRef is not non-IOSurface backed.

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;

size_t planeWidth[] = { width, width / 2 };
size_t planeHeight[] = { height, height / 2};
size_t planeBytesPerRow[] = { width, width / 2 };

CVReturn ret = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(
kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange,
data, bytesPerRow, 0, 0, 0, &pixelBuffer
);

if (ret != kCVReturnSuccess)
{
    NSLog(@"FAILED");

    CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);

    return;
}

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

// fails
CIImage * image = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);

[image release];
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 7):

I'll assume the question is: "Why do I get this error?"

To make an CVPixelBuffer IOSurface backed you need to set properties on the CVPixelBuffer when you create it.  Right now you are passing in "0" as the second to last parameter in CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes.

Pass a dictionary with a key for kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey and value that is an empty dictionary (to use default IOSurface options, others are not documented) in CVPixelBufferCreate (as you can't use kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey with CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes), copy correct bytes to created CVPixelBuffer (don't forget bytes alignment).  That is how you make it IOSurface-backed.

Although I'm not sure if it will remove all errors for you because of the pixel format.  My understanding is that the GPU has to be able to hold textures in that pixel format in order to be used as IOSurfaces though I'm not 100% sure.

Note: correct copying pixel bytes for kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange could be found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31839916/1735276).